# Get value from GridView

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get the value from a GridView and save it as a Session variable.

I know the column name and there is only ever one value in the GridView. What is the best way to select it and save as the Session variable?

The column name is CustomerID and the value is always a int.

Comment: What type of column is it? A `BoundField`?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/625303/122005)

Comment: Grid can have many rows - do u know the row number?

Comment: This will always return one row only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if there is one column and one row in the GridView you can try below.

```
Session["MySessionValue"]=  GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

but exception can be thrown when you access by index if there is no records in the GridView. So better to check `GridView1.Rows.Count` First and get the value

Comment: Where you databind? and where you want this value?

Comment: The reason I ask as it doesn't seem to be saving anything. Should I wait for the page to have loaded to call the code? I just want is saved to a session and I then use this on the next page the user clicks through to.

Comment: Ah sorted it. .Cells[0] should of been .Cells[1]

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `DataKey` for GridView as  **CustomerID** and select by:

`int ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[indx].Value);`

`indx` is Row Index in GridView..

Comment: I have an error saying Index was out of range. There is only one row in the GridView and tried 0 and 1 and still got the same error.

Comment: As I know the column name is there a way just to select this? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: what is your function to select a row?

Comment: So you can select by `GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[CustomerID]` and convert it to int..

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proper way to do this, you better hardcode the cellindex but anyways a little longer version of Damith's answer

```
if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int indexofcolumn = 0;
    foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
    {
        if (column.HeaderText == "CustomerID") break;
        indexofcolumn++;
    }
    Session["CustomerID"] = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[indexofcolumn].Text;
}
```